# Does there exist a simply connected surface with CM whose cotangent bundle is ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, fundamental-group

Does there exist a smooth projective complex surface $X$ such that,

(1) $\pi_1(X) = 0$

(2) $\Omega_X^1$ is ample

(3) the Mumford-Tate group of $H^2(X)$ is a torus

There exist examples with any two of these properties. Indeed:

(1) + (2) consider a generic codimension 2 complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^4$

(1) + (3) consider any rational surface or for a general type example take the Fermat hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$

(2) + (3) consider a fake projective plane since it is a ball quotient and $H^{2}(X) = H^{1,1}(X)$.

However, I cannot see how to get all three properties simultaneously.

Comment: What about a codimension n-2 generic complete intersection in a projective n-space? This will satisfy 1 and 2 and by lefschetz its H2 is one dimensional.

Comment: Surely $H^2$ won't be one-dimensional. I think the generic complete intersection does not have CM. Maybe a special one does, if the period map was open maybe you can even prove it.

Comment: Whoops my bad. I confused the dimensions. The period map is Unramified (Flenner). It is thus generically etale over its image. Does that give what you need?

Comment: There's an interesting argument in Prop. 9 of this paper by Beauville https://jep.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/jep.5.pdf that maybe could be adapted. I am not sure.